# If an object typed as any is sent using the spread operator on props, TS aborts checking

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Looking at the following code example

```
// Component.tsx file
import React from "react";

export const Component = ({ title, subTitle }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{subTitle}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// Props declared here
type Props = {
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
};
```

```
// App.tsx file
import { Component } from "./Component";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const componentData: any = {
    title: "Hello",
    subTitle: "Hello from comp"
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      // TS does not show an error here even though randomProp is not described on Component's Props
      <Component {...componentData} randomProp="string" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, on line 5 in `App.tsx` the `componentData` object is typed as any.
On line 11, in the return of the `App.tsx` I send that object as props for another component using the spread operator.

If I do that, TS aborts checking the rest of the props that are sent, as you can see `randomProp="string"` does not throw an error.

If I remove the `:any` typing from the object on line 5, then TS marks the `randomProp="string"` as non existing on the props of `Component` (I expected this to happen with `:any` on line 5 as well).

The follwing example does not use destructuring and TS shows the error this way

```
// App.tsx file
import { Component } from "./Component";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const componentData: any = {
    title: "Hello",
    subTitle: "Hello from comp"
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component 
       title={componentData.title}
       subTitle={componetData.subTitle}
       // TS shows an error here!
       randomProp="string"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more information:

Please have a look at this CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-worker-td2g0u?file=/src/App.tsx .

And also this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-monad-ygkloq?file=/src/App.tsx

Is this intended behaviour or a bug? How does this work underneath?

Comment: Expected `:any` to disable all further checks for the object that is typed as any, not when that object is sent as a function parameter.
So I was expecting `componentData.anything` to not throw an error ofcourse, but was not expecting this, hence the question.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler
Also it only happens when using destructuring, as you can see here if I send each prop individually it shows the error.
https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-monad-ygkloq?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with react or jsx; as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaE7yN) you can reproduce the issue without such dependencies.  Spreading an `any` object into another object turns the whole thing into `any` and there are no "excess properties" in `any`. (e.g., `any & {randomProp: string}` is eagerly reduced to `any`)  This is almost certainly intended behavior... the whole point of `any` is to turn off type checking. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is explicitly meant to turn off type checking, and it tends to be "infectious" or "contagious" in that combining `any` with other types often results in `any`.  So if you want type checking, a good general rule is: **avoid `any` as much as possible**.

---

Still, if you need to use it, you should learn more detail of how it interacts with other types and when it "takes over" other types and when it doesn't.  Let's start with this:

```
type Props = {
    title: string;
    subTitle: string;
};
const componentData: any = {
    title: "Hello",
    subTitle: "Hello from comp"
};
```

Since `componendData` is of type `any`, the compiler will let you index into it with any key you want, and the resulting property will also be of type `any`:

```
const title = componentData.title;
// const title: any
const subTitle = componentData.fsfsdjfiwjwi;
// const subTitle: any
```

If you make an object literal with `any`-typed values as property values, only those properties will have `any` types; it doesn't "infect" the whole object:

```
const objLit = {
    title: title,
    subTitle: subTitle,
    randomProp: "abc"
};
/* const objLit: {
    title: any;
    subTitle: any;
    randomProp: string;
} */
```

So if you try to assign such an object literal to a variable of type `Props`, the compiler will happily accept the `any` properties (even though it can't verify them, which is the point of `any`), but it will catch [excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), because the object literal is aware of their existence:

```
const excess: Props = {
    title: componentData.title, // okay
    subTitle: componentData.fsfsdjfiwjwi,  // okay
    randomProp: "abc" // error!
};
```

---

Now let's compare to what happens when you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) an `any`-typed value into an object literal:

```
const objSpread = {
    ...componentData,
    randomProp: "abc"
};
// const objSpread: any
```

Conceptually a spread will result in something very much like the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the spreaded object type with the type for the rest of the object literal.  (For spreads with known keys the compiler will try to represent overwritten properties more accurately, but for generic or other unknown-key types, it uses the intersection.)  And the intersection of `any` with any other type is just `any`:

```
type IntersectAny = any & { randomProp: string };
// type IntersectAny = any
```

So that `objSpread` value is now of type `any`.  The compiler has completely forgotten about `randomProp`.  And that means if you assign such an object literal to a value of type `Props`, the compiler will not see any excess properties, because `any` doesn't have any "excess" properties:

```
const noExcess: Props = {
    ...componentData,
    randomProp: "abc" // okay
};
```

---

So there you go.  If you spread an `any` into an object literal it "infects" the whole object and becomes `any`.  But if you add properties of type `any` individually to an object, the `any` type will be confined to just those properties.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBT1YAS2ABsIAuKZYOQgOwHMBuXfZAVwCMAVYsy6rUYsAvi2wBjBHWpQpAWzDSIdYABEAhsA2UNdEOiys8RUhSgAiABIQSJBBYA0xql15nK12-agAzRPJyCIoW2GLYEVIywAR80BgKSnQq6loaAHSmZCwA9DlB0bEeUHogktKyHDxxhonKqpra6b7ILQAmAFa+hADuHT2EuflRlW5xuvqRFTEInB0AMsSGOPhF-GsQzqtV7us7cVv4cHptwfBInhqcEqHhOQBUBbKzC8SUK-hZ5qUs22PFPxcxzop3k5zAAho9GYYSg9xyU0KEAAHhIIMhkJRwagMB8TOMgop6qkml9Dnh9sU6skGmlmq1kJ1un0BuSoMDQeDLtdbuIRjM5gBlMBwCAaNrLFzpaXUlKNDRsjlnRAQyxXG5hIZPAUdYWi8UTMrYUCQKAASVUEDgyAgEmAAEF9IZSlAAGRYdknZUXKhQxhQO75E3QC3AK02u2OgwYUqI2R0BAAUVR6MxsBVOKMq2l6VltO0iq9YJV3I14SAA)